# Unknown Insect identification

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]Found this bugger crawling across my laptop.  Any help identifying would be appreciated.  After a bunch of googling it appears to be close to a lady beetle larva.  I am located in north east USA.

[image: Bug Crawling]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks most like a common Green Lacewing larva - Chrysoperla rufilabris. Lacewings are considered a benefit in the garden because they effectively feed on aphids and other soft bodied garden pests. Here are some links that may be of further help.

https://bugguide.net/node/view/16103

http://www.uky.edu/Ag/CritterFiles/casefile/insects/lacewings/lacewings.htm

https://greenmethods.com/chrysoperla/